# How to navigate to a different .html page in Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

Hi guys I am trying to click a button in my Vue.js page to a different .html page that exist in my public folder.
So I am using this way

```
      <button @click="window.location='public/test.html'">See Results</button>
```

However I get an error that says

"Property or method "window" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

How do i navigate to a different page in Vue.js?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using vue-router if you're doing the spa approach. It will prevent your page from refreshing when you go to a different page and it will be much faster. But if you don't want to do that you could just use an anchor tag to handle the navigation for you.

```html
 <a href="/test.html">
 <button>See Results</button>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call a method `@click="navigateToTestHtml"` and put your code in it

```
methods: {
   navigateToTestHtml() {
      window.location='public/test.html'
   }
}
```

However, as `Vue` is a Single Page Application I think it would be better to create another page and add routing for it. [Vue Routing Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/)

Comment: how do I route? the documentation is horrible

Comment: Here is one standard example of the other documentation:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html
Basically, you load different child component when changing routes.

Comment: Another example - tutorial: https://flaviocopes.com/vue-router/

Comment: they all do not apply practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write 'window' into button tag, because window is not defined.I suggest that can write into 'methods',eg:

```
methods: {
  goToHtml() {
    window.location = 'public/test.html';
  }
}
```

But, if you use vue.js, I recommend you use vue-router. One page navigate to another page, eg:

```
methods: {
  goToPage() {
    this.$router.push('/another/page');
  }
}
```

[vue-router navigation usage](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)